# Are there good resources for porting mod_perl to Catalyst & is it worth it?

Tags: perl, porting, mod-perl, catalyst

We have a big e-learning mod_perl web app, which use AxKit, XML, XLST and javascript primarily running on a unix server. What I've came to notice is that the codes are rather messy, and there has been a few generations of developers coming in and out. Due to the current structure, the task of trying to make a simple hello world webpage involves writing a few components to get it work, due to the AxKit XSL transformation thingy.

So, I'm looking at the powerful Catalyst framework, and the MVC itself is making me drool. I'm looking for resources and best practices to see if porting the current web app over to Catalyst is feasible.

I would like to hear from fellow Catalyst-ers if the move will be worth it in case my management ask the magic question, why?

thanks :)

Comment: Well, I'd like to hear about staging a port from pure mod_perl to catalyst.  Sounds doable with some mod_proxy rules, and hacking the session code to me, but I develop different kinds of app to this.

Comment: You can run a Catalyst server under mod_perl. So your question should be about converting from a CGI model to a Catalyst model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be "it depends on how much AxKit are you using". If you're just using XSLT and not XSP, XPathScript, or any of the styles dynamic stuff then it'll probably be pretty straight forward. If you're using some of the more interesting creatures in the AxKit universe then you'll certainly want to take a deeper look at how well Catalyst can support things like XPathScript and XSP (as far as I know there isn't any support currently). If you're looking at dumping XML/XSLT entirely then it's certainly easier to go down the Catalyst path than not.

I know several of the AxKit developers have used, and do use Catalyst for some projects and even the most stubborn of them will probably admit that Catalyst is powerful and easy to achieve some goals. AxKit is a more specialized tool for people who want the "xkit xsl transformation thingy."

If you're on irc.perl.org come ask in the #axkit-dahut channel, we have both AxKit and Catalyst core developers ;)

Comment: @perigrin, thanks dude, i'll definitely check out the irc site when i can, cause my company prohibits irc from our work pc:(